# Find a least one substring in a string

Tags: php

I have a table of languages:

**Users**:

```
    Id languages
    --------------------------
    1  english,french,german
    2  english,german
    3  english,french
    4  french
```

And I have a drop down list of checkboxes (below).
I want to give the user the ablity to search for substring of some language inside of the languages that each id have like presented in the user table.

For example - if checkbox "french" will be mark then it will give on the page the results of id's 1 3 and 4.

I thought of using "find in set" function but how?

This is the code:

```
         var expanded = false;

        function showCheckboxes() {
          var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
          if (!expanded) {
            checkboxes.style.display = "block";
            expanded = true;
          } else {
            checkboxes.style.display = "none";
            expanded = false;
          }
        }   
        </script>

<tr>
      <td>Languages</td>
      <td dir="rtl">

          <form method="post" action="exxx.php">
          <div class="multiselect" dir="rtl">
          <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()" dir="rtl">
        <select>
        <option>choose:</option>
        </select>
        <div class="overSelect" dir="rtl"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="checkboxes">
        <label for="one">  
            <input type="checkbox"  id="one" name="languages[]" 
            value="english">english</label>
            <label for="two">
            <input type="checkbox" id="two" name="languages[]" value="french" 
             >french</label>
            <label for="three">
            <input type="checkbox" id="three" name="languages[]" 
            value="arabic">german</label>
      </div>
  </div>  
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
   </form>
```

Now, This "languages" field are one of some search fields that I have so I want to extract this queries:

```
$query = "select * from where 1=1,..."

$query.=" AND  
find_in_set(ITEM1 of checkboxes selected, languages) <> 0 OR 
find_in_set(ITEM2 of of checkboxes selected ,languages) <> 0 OR ...
etc.
```

Any suggestions?

Even if I will normalize the table: my problem is mainly to get the value from the drop down list and search by them. I don't know how many items were selected so I can't write

```
Select where languages = '$languages[0]' OR languages='languages[1]'
```

I will throw me an offset I there were only one selected.

Comment: this would be so easy if you just normalised your db data: http://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/first-normal-form-1nf.php

Comment: my problem is mainly to get the value from the drop down list and search by them.

Comment: If it was normalized, you could use WHERE ... IN.

Comment: select id from tb where  languages(the array from the search( in (select languages from tb)?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of listing languages in one column of your users table, create another table to link users to languages, like this:

```
user_languages:

user_id   language
   1      english
   1      french
   1      german
   2      english
   2      german
   3      english
   3      french
   4      french
```

Then you'll be able to use [the IN operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) to match rows with a list of values from your checkboxes.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM user_languages WHERE language IN('french','german')
```

This will work for any number of checkboxes selected. A brief example of how to do this with a PDO prepared statement:

```
$placeholders = rtrim(str_repeat('?,', count($_POST['languages'])));
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM user_languages WHERE language IN($placeholders)";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($_POST['languages']);
$ids = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Comment: Is there a way to write this without pdo?

Comment: Sure, you could a different database extension instead. mysqli, if your database is MySQL.

Comment: how can I normlize a table in mysql? could you give me a littel help with this? thank's!